# Entity framework Self Tracking

Tags: entity-framework

i'm new with EF but i have alot of experiance with SQL
        i tring to do very simple insert

i have two tables Persons and Address, the relation is 1 to many the Edmx create navigation property between the two.

Let say i have Person and i want to add Address.

```
     Person p = GetPesron(); // OK

     var newAddress = new Address {Id=1,City="ddd", Person =p};

     context.Addres.AddObject(d);
     context.SaveChanges();
```

Very Simple but not working , get excpetion 
Can't insert Id NULL to table Address !!!!!!
which i send id =1.
any other way ex: applay changes on Person.Address() still same error
what i'm missing here ?

Please advice 
thanks

Comment: Posting he exception in your question could be helpful too.

Comment: Without information about your Address.Id mapping we can hardly help you. What is a value of StoreGeneratedPattern in Id's properties?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ObjectContext.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) and [ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ObjectContext.DetectChanges() can help you.